# Bootstrap collapsible expandable vertical menu that allows only one open group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and I'm trying to create a collapsible/expandable vertical navigational menu using nav pills that will allow only one menu item group to be expanded at once.

I have 3 menu item groups, each with sub-menus. When the menu item is clicked, it expands to display the list of sub-menu items for the group. If I click another group, the new group opens as well, leaving the first group still open.

The problem I have is that I want to allow only one group to be open at the same time. So if a menu item group is open and I click on another menu group, I want the prior opened group to close.  I would like to mimic the behavior of the accordion.

Comment: [bootstrap accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) will not work for u?

Comment: No, because I would like to use the nav pills.

Answer (score 0):

combining these two examples you can reach a complete working result

1. menu example `[http://jsfiddle.net/gstvoo/zoxqpftc/][1]`

an example bootstrap menu with sub menu (duplicate the li with sub menu and change the ID's so they will be unique)

2. script solution `[http://jsfiddle.net/RfsS9/5/] [2]`
   use the jQuery script in this example and change the targeted class of the menu